# Why doesn't the "Close original message window when replying or forwarding" option from within Outlook 2010 work all of the time?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook has a setting that can be found under File/Options/Mail entitled "Close original message window when replying or forwarding" - the idea is that when this box is checked, when either replying to a message or forwarding that message after opening it, the original message window is closed so that after either replying or forwarding the email, you are immediately taken back to whichever folder was previously opened. I've noticed, however, that this feature doesn't consistently work - if I choose to sometimes reply to a message when its window is open, Outlook doesn't always close the message window which then requires me to do it manually. Are there any specific conditions that cause this feature not to work?

Comment: Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version. I tested in my environment and can't reproduce your issue. Since this is a random issue, please notice what specific operation you are doing when this issue occur. Then if the issue happen often, it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) for a while and see if the issue continues.

Answer (score 0):

I had both "Open replies and forwards in a new window" AND "Close original message window when replying or forwarding" and had the same problem.  The fix for me is apparently to UNcheck the "new window" one.   Good luck!